# Does the Python framework nose support testing a function which inititializes a daemon thread

Tags: python-2.7, nose

I am new on Stackoverflow and at Python.
I wrote a simple Python program as follows:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

import time
g_log_queue = Queue()
def print_log():
        while True:
                record = g_log_queue.get()
                if record == 'a':
                        print 'a is out'
                elif record == 'b':
                        print 'b is out'
                else:
                        print 'other is out'    


def run():
        g_log_thread = Thread(target=print_log,name='logthread',args=())
        g_log_thread.daemon = True
        g_log_thread.start()

        g_log_queue.put('a')
        g_log_queue.put('b')
        g_log_queue.put('c')

run()
```

Now, I write a demo test case for the program as follows:

```
from nose.tools import *
from pdaemon import *


def test_run():
        run()
```

When I run the nosetest command, I get this message:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
Exception in thread logthread (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
  File "/root/python/daemon/pdaemon.py", line 7, in print_log
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 179, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 279, in notify
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Do nose support testing the function which initializes a daemon thread?

Answer (score 0):

It's the python bug http://bugs.python.org/issue14623
The workaround is to add timeout

```
time.sleep(1)
```

in the end of script that allows the threads to finish before the script comes to end of life and close